# How to combine StackPanel and Grid within one XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `UserControl`, which contains (inside a main `Grid`) a `StackPanel` with a margin, which creates a rectangle within my `UserControl`, this is very easy:

```
<Grid Name="mainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="15">
```

Result:

[image]

I know that it is very easy to "split" a `UserControl` in different parts (because I want to add a contextmenu in the lower part of the `UserControl`):

```
<Grid Name="mainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.77*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.23*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
```

Result:

[image]

Now I would like to get both combined: I want my `UserControl` to contain both a StackPanel and a Grid, but that seems not to be that simple:

```
<Grid Name="mainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.77*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.23*"></RowDefinition>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="15">
```

Expected result:

[image]

Actual result is an error message:

```
XLS0509
Property elements cannot be in the middle of an element's content. 
They must be before or after the content.
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You did not post the complete XAML.  Edit your post to show the rest of it, after the declaration of the `StackPanel` to the end of the containing `Grid`

Comment: @Joe. I'm really sorry, but I tried it again and now it works, I have no idea what I did wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess what you've done wrong from your xaml posted.

I suspect you have something outside of your grid and within the user control tags. I can't replicate that particular error. But I can make it work.

This works fine for me:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp7.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp7"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Name="mainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.77*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.23*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="15">
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="20" Width="20"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, this is what I have tried before and which did not work, but now for some magical reason it seems to work anyway. Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: Now I've seen it: my "maingrid" had some row- and columndefinitions. Those needed to be defined directly after the declaration of the "maingrid", and I had added that new `Grid` just before those definitions. Sorry for the burden.